# mod_rewrite directives prevents access to mod_status

Tags: apache-2.4, windows-10

I want to enable [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) for myself in my Windows 10 development box, where I run Apache/2.4.6. I use name-based virtual hosts and I have a default host that points to a "Site does not exist" page:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Sites/Default/htdocs"
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common

    <Directory "C:/Sites/Default/htdocs">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I load all the required modules (mod_authz_core, mod_authz_host, mod_info  and mod_status) but none of my `Require` directives worked:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    
    # AH01753: access check of 'localhost' to /server-info failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
    #Require host localhost
    
    # AH01630: client denied by server configuration
    Require ip 127.0.0.1

    # ... but this:    
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Even allowing free access to everybody, I was getting my default `index.php` page due to having this in my default host:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've two questions:

- Is there something wrong in the `Require` directives that trigger AH01753 and AH01630?
- Is `RewriteRule` supposed to bypass `SetHandler server-status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/server-status isn't a file or directory, so if you insist on using mod_rewrite at least add a condition for this URI, otherwise that behaviour is normal.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status
```

By the way if you had gone to:

```
FallBackResource /index.php
```

You wouldn't be having this problem now. This is another example of using mod_rewrite when it is not needed, causing confusion.

Comment: If I understood correctly, mod_rewrite has precedence over Location and SetHandler so it has to deal with them and explicitly let them through. The solution is of course [FallBackResource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource), which has been available since Apache 2.2.16 but, surprisingly, it's vastly unknown (I've never seen a PHP framework that suggests it for route handling, even in 2017). Thank you very much.

Comment: precisely because it has precedence it was checking your conditions and rewrite as specified. And yes, FallbackResource is vastly unknown because nowadays the trend is copy pasting rewrite rules from other places without thinking about how to improve them with simpler configuration setups.